# Registry: Shell Open Command - Open multiple programs

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, windows-registry, cmd.exe

I'm trying to register a shell open command via the registry and want to open more than one program, so I tried it like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\myFile\Shell\Open\Command]
@="cmd /k calc & notepad & exit"
```

`calc` and `notepad` are just an example to demonstrate it.

If I use it like this, the calculator and Notepad are opened, but the command prompt is still open until I close Notepad. If I change it to `cmd /k calc & calc & exit`, I get 2 calculator instances and the command prompt is closed as I want it.

Why is it not working with Notepad?

Does anybody know another way to start multiple programs with the shell open command in the registry without having the command prompt stay open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by instead using the following command:

```
cmd /k start calc & start notepad & exit
```

Therefore making your `.reg` file into:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\myFile\Shell\Open\Command]
@="cmd /k start calc & start notepad & exit"
```

The reason why `calc` works fine (in Windows 10, but not in Windows 7) is that the `calc.exe` process starts a different process (`Calculator.exe`) and then exits, allowing the command to proceed.

This isn't so for `notepad.exe`, which means that the command gets stuck there waiting for `notepad.exe` to close.

The [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command is used to start a process in a separate window so that `cmd` can continue with the next step.